# わけ used in questions

Tags: word-choice

I have been watching quite a lot of anime and they sometimes they finish their questions with わけ.

What is the nuance between:

> 何がおかしいわけ？
>
> 何がおかしい？

I found the question below that answers most of my doubts, but I would like to know if that わけ is a set expression or if it's still related to the reason-ish わけ meaning. I also would like to know if わけですか is possible like のですか.

[What function does わけ have in this question?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/95349/what-function-does-%e3%82%8f%e3%81%91-have-in-this-question)

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2250/5010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost always used to express annoyance or to add accusation to the question. In some context it may merely mean "why not".

For example, if someone says「英文じゃないとだめなわけ？」it may merely mean "Why can it not be Japanese instead?". But this only works if the speaker is in a "higher position". If e.g. a subordinate uses it it will sound aggressive.

More often it's used to express annoyance or to accuse someone. E.g. if you say 「どこ行ってたわけ？」it's unambiguously an accusation and clearly indicates the speaker is angered.